# Not able to add the size of the product to the cart in the Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on a Ionic Ecommerce App and I have added the size of the product but the problem is that if the product has 4 sizes, the user is able to select the 4 sizes but it is wrong. User can only select only one size and move it to cart but the problem is that size is not adding to the cart.

This is my **productdetails.html**:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Products</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<ion-row align-items-center class="mynewr11">
 <ion-col *ngFor="let product of this.pdeta" col-5 class="mynewcol22">
  <img class="myimg11" src="{{product.image}}" />
  <p>{{ product.product_name }}</p>
  <p><strong>Actual Price:</strong>
    <span [ngStyle]="product.discount === '0' ? {'text-decoration':'none'} : {'text-decoration':'line-through'}">
      ₹{{product.product_price * product?.count}}
    </span>
  </p>
  <p><strong>Discount:</strong> {{product.discount}}%</p>
  <p><strong>Discount Price:</strong> ₹{{ product.product_actual_price * product?.count }}</p>
  <ion-col class="qty">
    <button (click)="decreaseProductCount(product)" clear ion-button small color="dark" class="mynewbtn11">
      -
    </button>
    <button ion-button small clear color="dark" class="mynewbtn11">
      {{product?.count}}
    </button>
    <button (click)="incrementProductCount(product)" clear ion-button small color="dark" class="mynewbtn11">
      +
    </button>
</ion-col>

<button *ngFor="let psize of product.product_size" (click)="toggleOnSize(psize)" [ngClass]="psize.onSize ? 'mynewbtn22' : 'newbtn11' " ion-button small>
  {{ psize.size }}
</button>

  <button class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button small>
    Add to Cart
  </button>
  <button ion-button icon-only class="wish-list-btn card" (click)="toggleOnWishlist(product)" color="light" class="mywisbtn11">
    <ion-icon [name]="product.onWishlist ? 'ios-heart' : 'heart-outline' "></ion-icon>
  </button>
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

In this HTML, I am showing the products with the sizes.

This is my **productdetails.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from '../../providers/cart/cart';
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-productdetails',
  templateUrl: 'productdetails.html',
})
export class ProductdetailsPage {
  detailsp: any = [];
  pdeta: any = [];
  items: Object[] = [];
  itemsInCart: Object[] = [];
  selectProduct: any;
  totalPrice: any;
  productCount: number = 1;
  cartItems: any[];
  noproducts: boolean = false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.detailsp = this.navParams.get('productdet');
    this.pdeta = this.detailsp.msg;
    this.pdeta.forEach(product => product.count = 1);
    console.log(this.detailsp);
    if(this.detailsp.msg.length === 0)
    {
      this.noproducts = true;
    }
    if (this.navParams.get("productdet")) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('ProductdetailsPage', JSON.stringify(this.navParams.get("productdet")));
    }
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getSingleProduct();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProductdetailsPage');
    this.selectProduct = this.navParams.get("productdet");
    this.cartService.getCartItems().then((val) => {
      this.cartItems = val;
    })
  }

  getSingleProduct() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('productdet') != 'undefined') {
      this.selectProduct = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('productdet'))
    }
  }

  addToCart(detailsp) {
    var productPrice = this.productCount * parseInt(detailsp.product_actual_price);
    let cartProduct = {
      product_id: detailsp.id,
      name: detailsp.product_name,
      image: detailsp.image,
      count: detailsp.count,
      psize: detailsp.size,
      disprice: detailsp.product_price,
      discountp: detailsp.discount,
      productPrice: this.productCount * parseInt(detailsp.product_actual_price),
      totalPrice: productPrice,
    };
    console.log(cartProduct);
    this.cartService.addToCart(cartProduct).then((val) => {
      this.presentToast(cartProduct.name);
    });
  }

  presentToast(name: any) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `${name} has been added to cart`,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'View Cart'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.navCtrl.push(CartPage);
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  decreaseProductCount(product) {
    if(typeof product.count === 'undefined') {
       product.count = 1;
    }
    if (product.count > 1) {
      product.count--;
    }
  }

  incrementProductCount(product) {
    if(typeof product.count === 'undefined') {
       product.count = 1;
    }
    product.count++;
  }

  toggleOnWishlist(product){
    product.onWishlist = !product.onWishlist;
  }

  toggleOnSize(psize){
    psize.onSize = !psize.onSize;
}
}
```

In this file, 2 functions are related to size, addToCart(detailsp) and toggleOnSize(psize). But the problem is that, when I console the console.log(cartProduct), it is showing the psize undefined because I am not able to select the size and send it to the addToCart function. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

In this image, I am showing the problem is that user is able to select the all the sizes and when I console the data it is showing the psize undefined. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Set detailsp.size property in function "toggleOnSize(psize)" or can use separate variblae for selected size.

Comment: @Musab. I have added the select option so it is working now but I have some problem that when i click to select option of one product, all products size are changing automatically. Can you solve this problem.

Comment: do you have separate selectedSize property for each product?

Comment: @Musab. <ion-select placeholder="Select Size" [(ngModel)]="productsize">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let psize of product.product_size" value="{{psize.size}}">{{psize.size}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>. Yes, but can ypu please check?

Comment: You have binded all the products with the common property "productsize".

Comment: <ion-select placeholder="Select Size" [(ngModel)]="product.SelectedSize"> <ion-option *ngFor="let psize of product.product_size" value="{{psize.size}}">{{psize.size}}</ion-option> </ion-select>

Comment: @Musab. Okay that solved my problem but how to fetch this value in the cart. I was using this.SelectedSize, but now it is not working.

Comment: product.SelectedSize will give size of each product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187040/discussion-between-raghav-and-musab).

Comment: @Musab. Thank you for the your answer. It has solved my query.

Comment: This is at least the 3rd time you asked a question like this in the last 2 weeks, all resulting of basically the same error. You should seriously consider working through the [Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) to learn the basics of template / component interaction. Also using `Object` and `any` for pratically all your data objects is not the way TypeScript is meant to be used. Consider defining custom `interfaces` for your data objects. This will save you from lots of problems down the road when your app grows.

Comment: @fridoo. Okay I will definitely work on my basics and thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define product.SelectedSize:any and use it everywhere to fetch size just like you are fetching any other property of product

Comment: Thank you for the your answer. It has solved my query.